# Issues with passing Parameters in ActionListener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have some issues in passing some parameters to the Action Listener method from the UI. Please find the code below. I have two textboxs and I will be passing the values of the textbox to the actionListener to perform some calculations

```
<h:commandButton  id="calculateButtonID"  value="Calculate" actionListener="#{adjustedBean.calculate}">
    <f:param name="targetInventoryDays" value="#{adjustedBean.adjustedQtyVo.targetDays}"></f:param>
    <f:param name="seasonalityFactor"  value="#{adjustedBean.adjustedQtyVo.seasonFactor}"></f:param>
       </h:commandButton>
```

When I try to get the values of the parameters in the ActionListener method, the values does not seem to get passed at the first click of the 'Calculate' Button. Only when I click the button, the second time, I seem to get the values/parameters that im passing. Can you please let me know what I need to do to get the values the first time, when I click on the calculate button.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is it a request scope ? if so try with view scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms indicate that those parameters are not available at the moment the page with the form is been rendered (which is exactly when those `<f:param>`s will be interpreted). It look much like that you've actually bound those values to the input elements of the very same form.  This way the `<f:param>`s will indeed only be filled when you actually submit the form with the values filled in (as would happen on 1st click). This explains why the 2nd click and on works.

You unfortunately didn't elaborate the concrete functional requirement in any way in your question, but I understand that you merely want to collect the submitted input values of the very same form as the action button which are been definied as follows:

```
<h:inputText value="#{adjustedBean.adjustedQtyVo.targetDays}" />
<h:inputText value="#{adjustedBean.adjustedQtyVo.seasonFactor}" />
```

In that case, you don't need the `<f:param>` for this at all. JSF has already updated the model values at the moment the action method is invoked. Just **remove** those `<f:param>` tags and get the submitted values as follows:

```
public void calculate() {
     System.out.println(adjustedQtyVo.getTargetDays());
     System.out.println(adjustedQtyVo.getSeasonFactor());
}
```